# What is the word for "aerial" but in the space

Tags: single-word-requests

Aerial means existing, happening, or operating in the **air**. I am wondering if there any word that has the same definition but in **space**?

Comment: You might think *spatial* is the adjective for *space*

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a word for `Unmanned Aerial Vehicle` but in space. Not sure `Unmanned Spatial Vehicle` will fit the context or not. (Also this is the first time I see this word)

Comment: *Sidereal* is really from the stars, but it could fit. Another option is *interplanetary*, which is not directly an answer to your question, but it is for what you really intended to ask: `Unmanned Interplanetary Vehicle`.

Comment: As a side note: German language has solutions for this, as in German *Weltraum* ("world space") is commonly used for *cosmos*, and this is productive for compound nouns such as *Weltraumfahrt* ("world space navigation"), and then from this the shorter *Raumfahrt* (space navigation) is derived.

Comment: Well, space probe, space drone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the context you pose, I would suggest "**cosmic**" or "**extraterrestrial**" as describing the specific "space" that you refer to in the question.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cosmic

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/extraterrestrial

Answer (score 0):

In comments you clarify,

> I was looking for a word for Unmanned Aerial Vehicle but in space. Not sure Unmanned Spatial Vehicle will fit the context or not.

*Unmanned space vehicle* would certainly be clear and to the point.

You might also call it an *unmanned spacecraft* or *unmanned space ship*.

In science fiction, writers have often mentioned things such as *space probes* or *drones* with a similar meaning.

In some cases, the name we use for the vehicle might make it clear that it travels in space, without having to use an extra word to say so.  For example, NASA calls its unmanned space vehicles, *unmanned satellites* (if they remain in Earth orbit) or *unmanned missions*. Wikipedia has a [List of unmanned NASA missions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unmanned_NASA_missions) that might provide other ideas for nomenclature.

Answer (score 0):

Space is accepted and is self-defining.  Why not use Unmanned **[Space](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/185414?rskey=P4r46Q&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)** Vehicle?

From Oxford English Dictionary:

> The expanse in which celestial objects are situated; the physical universe (excluding celestial objects) beyond the earth's atmosphere,
>   consisting of near vacuum with small amounts of gas and dust.

As in:  [article](https://www.boeing.com/defense/autonomous-systems/x37b/index.page)

> This United States Air Force **unmanned space vehicle** explores
>   reusable vehicle technologies that support long-term space ...

Answer (score 0):

You said in a comment under your question:

> Thanks, I was looking for a word for `Unmanned Aerial Vehicle` but in space. Not sure `Unmanned Spatial Vehicle` will fit the context or not. (Also this is the first time I see this word)

*Aerial* and *aeronautical* are adjectives for things in the atmosphere.

Analogously, the adjective for things in space is **astronautical**. (*Spatial*, while also analogous, doesn't really work in this case.)

---

From the noun [*astronautics*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/astronautical):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : the science of the construction and operation of vehicles for travel in space beyond the earth's atmosphere

---

As per another answer, *unmanned* ***space*** *vehicle* sounds more natural than *unmanned* ***astronautical*** *vehicle*.

However, when you talk about things manufactured for space *in general*, you are talking about things that are of an ***astronautical*** *nature*, not things that are of a ***space*** *nature*.